# Setter method in Java not storing StringBuilder correctly

Tags: java, input, stringbuilder, setter

I have an employee class that is to store an idnumber in a specific format (XXX-L) x's being ints 0-9 and L a letter from a-m and uppercase. I decided to use a StringBuilder as the field for that due to the mutability StringBuilder has for formatting the input and checking if it is correct.

In the main method, I make an instance of this class and ask for the id number to be inputted unformatted (like so: 123f). My setter method is as follows:

```
void setId(StringBuilder idNumber){
  
    if(idNumber.length() != 4 || !Character.isLetter(idNumber.charAt(3)) || Character.toUpperCase(idNumber.charAt(3)) > 'M' ) { 
      
        System.out.println("Please insert valid ID#");
        setId(programclassname.input());
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < idNumber.length()-1; i ++){      //looking to see if 0-2 are numbers
         
         if(!Character.isDigit(idNumber.charAt(i))){
            System.out.println("Please insert valid ID#: " );
            setId(programclassname.input());

         }
            
     }
    this.idNumber = new StringBuilder(idNumber); //if idNumber didn't trigger above conditions, set idNumber field to value of idNumber argument. 
    this.idNumber.replace(3,4,Character.toString(Character.toUpperCase(idNumber.charAt(3))));//replaces letter at end with uppercase version if it is not already uppercase
    this.idNumber.insert(3,"-");//add the hyphen
 }
```

The method works if you input a correct id the first time, but if you don't a few times and the methods recalls itself for you to input a correct one, I noticed the value stored into the StringBuilder field is the original incorrect string. Any ideas where I went wrong?

Comment: Unrelated to your question: Your code is quite hard to understand. You might consider choosing method parameter names which are not already used as member names (your IDE should complain...). Besides, I do not understand why you use `StringBuilder` here instead of plain Strings.

Comment: I like to use the same argument names as the fields and use "this" keyword to distinguish them, becuase the argument will be stored as the field.  I know its not the convention; is it that bad?

Comment: And I am using StringBuilder because of the mutability and methods that come with it. I am taking an input of 3 numbers and a letter and I need it formatted to "xxx-l". Regarding the recursion, I know the the loop would be faster but why else should I use a loop? The recursive call makes more sense logically to me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you set it in a recursive manner without returning when done. Insert a return; after the recursive call and it should do it.

Comment: hey, so where exactly do I insert the return  statement? I forgot about this aspect of recursion. I solved a similar issue before by clearing an arraylist after the recursive call, and the end of that method returned a value. But this is a setter and I'm not returning anything.

Comment: Right after each recursive call

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with recursion. When the method recalls for a new correct Id, it'll eventually return back to the original call having the wrong id in the idNumber field. That's why idNumber field is having the incorrect field.

You can correct this by using a return statement after getting the input.